# Preventing an event from propagating in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I have some navigation setup like this:

```
    <a (click)="onCustomParameters()">
        <app-custom-start-card></app-custom-start-card>
    </a>
```

When the user clicks on the `app-custom-start-card` the `onCustomParameters()` is fired, triggering navigation.

There is another button in the card that open an external link.  When clicked the external link is opened, and the `onCustomParameters()` is also fired.

For example there is this button inside the card:

```
<button (click)="issuesTab()">Issues</button> Github Repository.
```

The issues tab function does this:

```
  issuesTab(e:any) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    window.open(ISSUES_URL, '_blank');
  }
```

I thought perhaps e.stopPropagation() would do the trick, but no bieno.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try passing the `$event` to `issuesTab` in your template: `<button (click)="issuesTab($event)">`, otherwise `e` would be undefined. apart from that you're on the right track with `e.stopPropagation()`.